# Is it efficient to have a only-data MonoBehaviours on lots of game objects?

Tags: unity, monobehaviour

I'm working on a **voxel based game** and this solution would make the implementation of networking and other features a lot more easier, it is less error-prone, easier to edit in the Editor, etc.

So the question is:

- **How bad is it performance-wise to have lots of MonoBehaviours in the scene, if they don't implement any of the MonoBehaviour methods?**
- (So they only have primitive data stored in them)

Comment: `How bad is it performance-wise to have lots of MonoBehaviours in the scene, if they don't implement any of the MonoBehaviour methods?` Then why would they implement `MonoBehaviour`? What will you use them for?

Comment: I just want to store data about the objects they are attached to.

Comment: Then you can simply create a script that doesn't use `MonoBehaviour`, no?
Also performance-wise, if they only save data, they shouldn't need many resources, unless you plan to save millions of variables every frame.

Comment: But only mono behaviour descendants can be attached to an object. (Or not?)

Comment: The very best way to find out for sure is to run a test and profile it. Build a synthetic scene with tons of objects with a pile of MonoBehaviours storing random numbers, and profile that against an alternative, like storing the data in a big ol' array or map indexed by object position or identity. If you don't see a major measurable difference, then stick to whatever is simplest/most flexible for your use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are saving massive amount of information on those scripts, there is nothing performance-wise that you should worry about. If the only thing they do is have some getters/setters or something like that, the responsibility of performance is passed on who is calling them.

In most cases, it's not going to be a problem, but you did mention this is a voxel based game. The only thing I could see going wrong, is if you attached those scripts in every single voxel in the game, and had the game run getters and setters for multiple data, on every single voxel. This could potentially be quite expensive.

If you give some more information about what exactly you have in mind, maybe I can go into more detail. Also don't fall into the trap of [Premature Optimisation](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). If you have an idea, implement it, if it runs slow, profile it and optimise the slow parts.

Comment: Well, maybe there will ~10000 voxels at maximum. Currently I handle them together, based on what complex objects are they being part of. (So 1 Script per complex object) And modifying the voxels (like an explosions damages some of them) is calculated at the host and only the results should be transferred to the clients. Currently my 2 options are that every voxel has a data storing script attached to it (with an ID for example) and this ID will sent to the clients. The other is that all of the voxels have Network Identities attached so they are synced automatically.

Comment: The "1 Script per complex object" sounds correct. I'm not sure why you would need a unique ID for each voxel, you can give a unique ID for each complex object, and each voxel that it includes can simply have an index (as they will be part of an array I assume?).

Comment: Yes, which was my first approach as well, but I raycast the voxels on an explosion, and it gives back game objects. So for that reason I have a "GameObject" keyed dictionary, where the value is a "VoxelData". This way the voxel data can be reached very quick. But If I use an array and the index will be the unique identifier, then I will have to find every hit game object's voxel data by iterating through that array, and check whether that VoxelData has that GameObject or not. Instead of instantly reaching the VoxelData.

Comment: @Tudvari It sounds to me like you are over-complicating things. I may be wrong, as I don't have much experience with voxel games. My only real advice is, follow this plan, and if you see any performance issue, only then spend time to fix it.